# Use final output filename of maven-assembly-plugin in another plugin

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I am packaging a project using maven-assembly-plugin, to produce a jar which includes my dependencies:

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>${project.main.class}</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I am also using a custom plugin on the `install` phase to send this jar to a remote device using RMI:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>za.co.pietermuller.ev3</groupId>
    <artifactId>lejos-rmi-exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <configuration>
        <target>?????</target>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>lejos-rmi-exec</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Is there a way for me to use the exact output path and filename of the `maven-assembly-plugin` plugin when setting the `target` property of the RMI plugin?

I tried combinations of `${project.build.outputDirectory}` and `${project.build.finalName}` with some hardcoding, but none of these gave me exactly what I need.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what should be given as `target` to the `lejos-rmi-exec-maven-plugin` but if we suppose that you need the path to your generated jar (or zip or another format), the solution would be using properties.

At the root level of your pom (at the same level at the tag `build`), in the tag `properties`, add some properties like that for example :

```xml
<properties>
    <myproperties.myassembly.build.dir>${project.build.directory}/my-assembly-target-dir/</myproperties.myassembly.build.dir>
    <myproperties.myassembly.build.finalName>my-finalName-assembly</myproperties.myassembly.build.finalName>
</properties>
```

Then in the `maven-assembly-plugin`, in your execution, use them :

```xml
<execution>
    <id>testfinalName</id>
    <phase>package</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <finalName>${myproperties.myassembly.build.finalName}</finalName>
        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
        <outputDirectory>${myproperties.myassembly.build.dir}</outputDirectory>
        <descriptorId>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorId>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

There you know that the path of your file will be `${myproperties.myassembly.build.dir}/${myproperties.myassembly.build.finalName}.jar` (or .`your_choosen_format`) and you can use it in the target.

By default, the `maven-assembly-plugin` is using for the `finalName` the pattern `${project.artifact.artifactId}-${project.artifact.version}` to which it appends the `assemblyId` (follow by a dash `-`) if necessary. And then the format(s) are added when creating the archive(s).

To finish, if we suppose that the `target` needs the path to your generated file, your second plugin will look like (according to the fact that your generated assembly is a `jar` of course) :

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>za.co.pietermuller.ev3</groupId>
    <artifactId>lejos-rmi-exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <configuration>
        <target>${myproperties.myassembly.build.dir}/${myproperties.myassembly.build.finalName}.jar</target>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>lejos-rmi-exec</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```